# How to show image element from XML with php

Tags: php, html, xml

I've tried what others have posted on stack overflow but it doesn't seem to work for me. So could anyone help please.
I have this xml document with a structure of:

```
<surveys>
<survey>
<section>
<page>
<reference>P1</reference>
<image><! [CDATA[<img src="imagepath">]]></image>
</page>
<page>
<reference>P2</reference>
<image><! [CDATA[<img src="imagepath">]]></image>
</page>
</section>
</survey>
</surveys>
```

Then this is my PHP code to get the image to show up:

```
function xml($survey){
$result = "<surveys></surveys>";
$xml_surveys = new SimpleXMLExtended($result);
$xml_survey = $xml_surveys->addChild('survey');
if ("" != $survey[id]){
$xml_survey_>addChildData($survey['image']);
}
```

This is my other file:

```
 $image = “”;

 if(“” != $image){
        $image = <div class=“image_holder”> $image </div> 
   echo $image;
}
```

I'm not sure how to progress forward with this. so any help would be appreciated

Comment: that `xml` function does nothing with the processing it does - perhaps return something or echo or save might be better??

Comment: `$image` is nothing. Please show how you try to read `<image><! [CDATA[<img src="imagepath">]]></image>`

Comment: Edited my answer! (fixed answer after testing with PHP server, so retry now)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would like to fetch the image for a specific survey id. Well you can use DOM+Xpath To fetch this directly:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = 'string(
    /surveys/survey/section/page[reference="P1"]/image
)';
$imageForSurvey = $xpath->evaluate($expression);
var_dump($imageForSurvey);
```

Output:

```
string(22) "<img src="imagepath1">"
```

The content of the CDATA section inside the image element is a separate HTML fragment. You can use it directly if you trust the source of the XML or you parse it as HTML.

```
$htmlFragment = new DOMDocument();
$htmlFragment->loadHTML($imageForSurvey);
$htmlXpath= new DOMXpath($htmlFragment);

var_dump(
    $htmlXpath->evaluate('string(//img/@src)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "imagepath"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example-logic is trying to create XML, not load it ;-)

First you need to find the path and/or address to the XML file, like:

```
$filePath = __DIR__ . '/my-file.xml';
```

Then load XML:

```
<?php

$filePath = __DIR__ . '/my-file.xml';

$document = simplexml_load_file($filePath);

$surveyCount = 0;
foreach($document->survey as $survey)
{
    $surveyCount = $surveyCount + 1;
    echo '<h1>Survey #' . $surveyCount . '</h1>';
    foreach($survey->section->page as $page)
    {
        echo 'Page reference: ' . $page->reference . '<br>';
        
        // Decode your image.
        $imageHtml = $page->image;

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($imageHtml);
        $xpath= new DOMXpath($dom);

        $image = $xpath->evaluate('string(//img/@src)');
        if(!empty($image)) {
            echo '<div class=“image_holder”>' . $image . '</div>';
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

> **Note** that you should replace `<! [CDATA[` with `<![CDATA[` (without space),
> else you will get `StartTag: invalid element name` error probably.